# Should irq% be included in cpu% of a process?

Tags: performance, cpu, irq

We want to compute service demand of a web application on a multi-core server. In order to do so, we run load testing of the application for certain no of users and record the cpu% over the test duration. Once load test is done, throughput is obtained and [utilization law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_operational_analysis) is used to compute service demand. The cpu% for a process includes only usr% and sys% whereas irq% is included in the overall cpu% and not in the per process cpu%. But if the irq% is due to the application being accessed by a large no of clients, it should be included. Else, the bottleneck analysis may be inaccurate. 
In some cases, irq% constitutes more than 8% of cpu% for a process.